# Specify submit in jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web page with multiples submit and I'm using an ajax request to send one but I'm having troubles to select which submit button has has to be send.

I have this for the moment :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
      var value = $('#str').val();
       $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
         $("#search_results").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

It's working good on one submit button but all the others doesn't work anymore. 
I'm guessing this is because I select all of them instead of selecting one. 
I tried to changed this line `$("#lets_search").bind('submit',function()` and specify the name of the submit I want to send but it won't work...

Any ideas ? Thank you :)

Edit :

```
<form id="lets_search" method="POST" action="#">
    //my search bar
    Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">

    <div id="search_results"></div>

    //and let just imagine I have others submit button
    <input type="submit" value="ok" name="ok" id="ok">
    <input type="submit" value="hello" name="hello" id="hello">
</form>
```

After I use this ajax script, the search bar is working well, but the others submit button aren't working anymore.
So I want to specify in the ajax script, my submit button "send" instead of selecting all of them.

Comment: Is there a reason you're binding to the submit event handler of the form and not the click handler on the buttons?

Comment: It's not clear enough what you're trying to do .. and what is *multiples submit* mean?? .. And keep in mind *Ids suppose to be unique use class instead*

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Submit means submit buttons. I'm trying to make a search bar using AJAX. But I have a lot of others button in my form that are used for somethings else.

Comment: @pendo I didn't use click so I can submit the research with enter aswell.

Comment: Please post the form code too.

Comment: All the submit-buttons do the same thing, submit the form. I don't understand what you want to achieve here? Also jQuery bind is deprecated use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: @xarj if you press 'enter', which `name` / `submit` event should you send in the submission?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused :)  Why does it matter which submit button is pushed?  If the form is submitted, the form is submitted.  Can you explain more about what the problem is please?

Comment: @pendo let's button1 display "hello", button2 display "ok". When I press one button, the form will be submitted, but both buttons do different things. Problem solved, see answer below :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not bind ajax on a button click event?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(){
      var value = $('#str').val();
       $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
         $("#search_results").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Below is html:

```
<form id="lets_search" method="POST" action="#">
    //my search bar
    Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">

    <div id="search_results"></div>

    //and let just imagine I have others submit button
    <input type="submit" value="ok" name="ok" id="ok">
    <input type="submit" value="hello" name="hello" id="hello">
</form>
```

Try running below fiddle it will give you an idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send").click(function(){
        alert($("#value").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="value"/>
  <input type="button" id="send" value="Send"/>
  <input type="button" id="send1" value="Another button"/>
  <input type="button" id="send2" value="One more button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Than you it's working well. I tried $("input[type=submit][name=send]").on("click", function () {//}); before but it didn't work.

Comment: If I want instead of click, press enter. Should I just replace the line click with $('#str').keypress(function(event) { } ?

Comment: See this fiddle from @Maslo https://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/99w5g/. You will understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`submit` event is related to forms, not to buttons, you should probably move to `click` button on specific buttons?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#lets_search").on('click', '#ok', function() {
      var value = $('#str').val();
      alert('first button');
      $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data);
      });
      return false;
    });

    $("#lets_search").on('click', '#hello', function() {
      var value = $('#str').val();
      // The other one
      alert('second button');
      $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Html

```
<form id="lets_search" method="POST" action="#">
  //my search bar
  Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
  <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">

  <div id="search_results"></div>

  //and let just imagine I have others submit button
  <input type="submit" value="ok" name="ok" id="ok">
  <input type="submit" value="hello" name="hello" id="hello">
</form>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes, I tried this aswell just to see if it was working. I tried something like : $("input[type='submit'][name='send']").on("click", function(){  but didn't work

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work, when I click, nothings happens